# Using the Selected Item from Combo box in If Statement In Java

Tags: java

How can i use the selected item from combo box in `if` statement (the combo box value is converted to `string`), the java compiler shows an incompatible type error , saying `string` cannot be converted to `Boolean`. Please help :) Thank You in advance.

Code:

```
private void btnSignInActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    String userid = txtUserID.getText();
    String username = txtUserName.getText();
    String usertype = cmboUserType.getSelectedItem().toString();

    DBConnector dbcon = new DBConnector();
    dbcon.connect();


    if(dbcon.isUserExists(userid, username,usertype)){
        if (usertype = "Customer"){
           msg.showMessageDialog(
            this,
            "Login Successful",
            "Login Status",
            1);
        OrganicFoods.Customer cust = new OrganicFoods.Customer();
        cust.setVisible(true); 
        }
        else if ( usertype = "StoreAdmin"){
           msg.showMessageDialog(
            this,
            "Login Successful",
            "Login Status",
            1);

        OrganicFoods.StoreAdmin S1 = new OrganicFoods.StoreAdmin();
        S1.setVisible(true); 
        }
         else if ( usertype = "Collection_Delivery_Officer"){
           msg.showMessageDialog(
            this,
            "Login Successful",
            "Login Status",
            1);

        OrganicFoods.Collection_Delivery_Officer cdo1 = new OrganicFoods.Collection_Delivery_Officer();
        cdo1.setVisible(true); 
        }
    }else{
        msg.showMessageDialog(
            this,
            "Login Failure",
            "Login Status",
            0);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code/work you have done until now?

Comment: `usertype = "StoreAdmin"` is not how you compare Strings in Java, you should be using String#equals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`==` compares Object reference

`.equals()` compares String value

Also, to check conditions in your `if`/`else if` statements, you must use the `==` sign and not the `=` because the `=` operator will assign the value to the String and not compare it as you want.

Comparing `Strings` using the `==` sign is not the best way to check as it compares Objects and not values.
So, For the particular program you must use the code snippet as shown below :

```
if (usertype.equals("Customer")) {
    //your algorithm
}
```

Comment: Not very helpful, because you don't explain why. It is a duplicate question by the way

Comment: @Dici Edited. Please let me know if I missed something.